# Is it possible to use MongoRepository without using Spring Boot? Just plain Java + MongoDB CRUD program

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mongodb.quickstart.ConnectToMongoDB.findByUserId(ConnectToMongoDB.java:49)
    at com.mongodb.quickstart.ConnectToMongoDB.main(ConnectToMongoDB.java:41)
```

EmployeeRepository.java

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends MongoRepository<Employee,String>{

    Employee findByUserId(String userId);
    List<Employee> findByLocation(String location);
}
```

And then I call it here:

```
 public static boolean findByUserId(String userId) {
        
        Optional<Employee> employee = Optional.ofNullable(employeeRepository.findByUserId(userId));
        
        return employee.isPresent()? true: false;
    }
```

However I get NPE Exception above.

But when I just do this:

```
 public static void main( String[] args ) {
        // Replace the placeholder with your MongoDB deployment's connection string
        String uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
        try (MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(uri)) {
            MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("testdb");
            MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("employee");
            Bson bsonFilter = Filters.eq("userId", "1234567");
            //FindIterable<Document> queryResult = collection.find(bsonFilter);
            Document doc = collection.find(bsonFilter).first();
           
            if (doc != null) {
                System.out.println(doc.toJson());
            } else {
                System.out.println("No matching documents found.");
            }
        }
    }
```

I can fetch data from MongoDB and program works fine.

Comment: Not in a simple self actuating way, what you'd have to do is create your own factory for repositories and then initialize them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data definitely can be used without Springboot.
You need to define Configurations and Components Scan annotations for your project in order to tell Spring how to create the components.
@SpringBootApplication annotation includes all these annotation, that is why it finds all the components.